# Joining three tables on same primary Key MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join three tables on the first tables Primary key, of which both other tables possess a foreign Key.

Example

```
SELECT *
FROM team_member
INNER JOIN bench_member
ON team_member.team_member_id=bench_member.team_member_id
INNER JOIN player
ON team_member.team_member_id=player.team_member_id
```

Each join works individually, but when i try to combine them. it gives me empty result sets. Really confused as to what is going on here.

Comment: Can you please provide us the output you are getting vs expected output?

Comment: Is it possible that team_member_id is NULL in any of the tables?

Comment: Maybe because a team_member is either a bench_member or a player but not both? Are you sure you want to INNER JOIN?

Comment: @maraca you worded it better than i did :)

Comment: You should probably do two separate joins, one with `player` and another with `bench_member`, and then combine them with `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each team_member is either a bench_member or a player and not both, then you might want something like this. [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62231/3/0)

```
select t.*, 
    case when b.team_member_id is not null then 'Bench'
    when p.team_member_id is not null then 'Player'
end
from team_member t
left join bench_member b on t.team_member_id = b.team_member_id
left join player p on t.team_member_id = p.team_member_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Left Outer Joins instead. You will be better able to analyze data.